# Simple CSS formatting issue

Tags: css

I've created a simple page for processing three forms via jquery/ajax. Everything functions properly, but somehow I can't seem to debug this simple CSS issue.  I have a parent DIV, with three DIVs inside it, each one containing a form and the relevant success message when a form is submitted.  If someone could take a look at it I would really appreciate it.  You can find it here ([LINK](http://thenally.com/work/form-test)).  The style sheet can be seen through the source and is really simple.  I've included the gist of the page architecture below and the bit of CSS I've written.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">

     <div class="form-container">
          <form></form>
          <div class="success">
               <p>Form Success!</p>
          </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-container">
          <form></form>
          <div class="success">
               <p>Form Success!</p>
          </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-container">
          <form></form>
          <div class="success">
               <p>Form Success!</p>
          </div>
     </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrap{
    width:900px;
    height:450px;
    margin:25px;
    padding:0;
    }

div.form-container {
    background:#9c9;
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    }

div.success{
    background:#ffa07a;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

form {
    background:#999;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding:10px;
    }
```

You'll notice that the second and third form containers have 19px margins at the top, however this isn't reflected anywhere in the CSS.  I've been trying to debug this for hours to no avail.  I'm almost embarrassed to ask for help, as I know it must be something simple.  I've moved virtually every element around to find the issue, but nothing changes it!  I can get it working using negative margins to pull the two containers up, but I don't think I should need that kind of fix.

Thanks for taking a look,

Mike

Comment: you should avoid having the same unique identifier (`id`'s) in several elements... use a `class` for that, witch will make your example work as `div.success` means a `div` element with a `success` class, like: `<div class="success">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the only problem, but you have an id for the success div but your css is calling a success class.

`<div id="success">`

and your css is

```
div.success{
    background:#ffa07a;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Change your HTML to be

`<div class="success">`

**EDIT:**

In your text page, you have `BR`s after the `div`s.  Remove those and everything lines up.

Comment: sorry about that, i just was simplifying the code for clarity here...i've corrected that, and it is correct in the working example through the link in the OP

Comment: thanks @jason, I didn't even think of that...i'll test it and get back to you.

Comment: aaaand...you're right.  I can't believe I spent so much time on this...outrageous.  Thanks for the speedy feedback!

Answer (score 2):

I think the `<br>` tags between each `<div class="form-container">` are the causing the margins.

Comment: hey @lefters, you were right...I'm gonna mark Jasons as the answer just cause he got back to me fastest, but I really appreciate the feedback..+1